# Using a QTimer within a PyQt worker thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread, qtimer

I am working with serial device and set a flag (which is global variable) based on the received data. Now I want to reset the flag after a while (for example one second) by using a timer.

Here is the code:

```
class Inlet_Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Inlet_Worker, self).__init__()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Reset_Register_Barcode)

    def run(self):
        global Register_Barcode
        while True :
            if  client.read_coils(address = 0x0802).bits[0]:
                Register_Barcode = True
                self.timer.start(1000)
                
    
    def Reset_Register_Barcode(self):
        global Register_Barcode
        Register_Barcode = False
```

However the timer is not working.

Comment: First of all, do not use globals. Then, a while loop like that prevents any event to be processed. Add at least a small sleep interval, and create the timer inside `run`.

Comment: I put the timer inside `run`. Still not working and the following error:                                                                                                  `QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread`

Comment: @sames Did you try the solution in my answer? If it doesn't do what you want, please say why so I can try to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume from your example code that your are using a [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) and that you also use [QObject.moveToThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) on your worker object. This is the correct procedure, but there are some other things you must do to make your timer work.

Firstly, you should use a [single-shot timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-prop) so as to avoid re-regsitration whilst the current one is active. Secondly, you must explicitly process any pending events, since your while-loop will block the thread's event-loop. Without this, the timer's timeout signal will never be emitted. Thirdly, you should ensure that the worker and thread shut down cleanly when the program exits (which will also prevent any Qt error messages). Finally, if possible, you should use signals to communicate registration changes to the main GUI thread, rather than global variables.

The demo script below (based on your example) implements all of that. After the Start button is clicked, the thread will start and periodically update the regsitration (indicated by the check-box). Hopefully you shoudld be able to see how to adapt it to your real application:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Inlet_Worker(QObject):
    barcodeRegistered = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stopped = False
        self._registered = False
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateBarcodeRegistration)

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        self._stopped = False
        while not self._stopped:
            #if client.read_coils(address = 0x0802).bits[0]:
            count += 1
            if count % 20 == 0 and not self._registered:
                self.updateBarcodeRegistration(True)
                self.timer.start(2000)
            QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            QThread.msleep(100)
        self.updateBarcodeRegistration(False)
        self.timer.stop()
        print('Stopped')

    def updateBarcodeRegistration(self, enable=False):
        print('Register' if enable else 'Reset')
        self._registered = enable
        self.barcodeRegistered.emit(enable)

    def stop(self):
        self._stopped = True


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Inlet_Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.button = QPushButton('Start')
        self.check = QCheckBox('Registered')
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.check)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.thread.start)
        self.worker.barcodeRegistered.connect(self.check.setChecked)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.worker.stop()
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 200, 50)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```